# How to remove ALL songs from a YouTube playlist with google sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube

I have this script that removes videos from a youtube playlist.

```
function updateYTPlaylist() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const yt_video_ids  = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);
const playlistId =  "PL7Ias5xZGXQ-cRocGUGtJnS-x5Lbbgv-c";

const playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: playlistId});
const playlistItem = playlistResponse.items;
playlistItem.forEach(dvid =>
{YouTube.PlaylistItems.remove(dvid.id);
Utilities.sleep(2000);}
);
                                                         
}
```

The problem with this script is that it only removes 5 items per run. I need it to remove ALL videos in the playlist.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Here is the official documentation for the deletion of an item from a playlist. Unfortunately this http request only deletes one video from the playlist, so you will have to loop through all the id's of the videos the playlist has, deleting each one at a time.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete?hl=es

Comment: When I run the above script it removes 5 videos per run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the default value of `maxResults` is `5`. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. So when you want to retrieve the items more than `5`, please add `maxResults`.

### When the number of items is less than 50:

As the simple modification, when the number of items in the play list is less than 50, you can use the following modification.

#### From

```
const playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: playlistId});
```

#### To:

```
const playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: playlistId, maxResults: 50});
```

### When the number of items is more than 50:

When the number of items in the play list is more than 50, it is required to use `nextPageToken`. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
const playlistId =  "PL7Ias5xZGXQ-cRocGUGtJnS-x5Lbbgv-c";

let playlistItems = [];
let pageToken = "";
do {
  const playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: playlistId, maxResults: 50, pageToken: pageToken});
  playlistItems = playlistItems.concat(playlistResponse.items);
  pageToken = playlistResponse.nextPageToken || "";
} while (pageToken);

playlistItems.forEach(dvid => {
  YouTube.PlaylistItems.remove(dvid.id);
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
});
```

### Reference:

- [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)